# sturdy, metallic chess clock as carry-on baggage

Tags: usa, airport-security, hand-luggage, tsa

I am an amateur chess player and I am considering flying from the US to Europe with the following chess clock:

[https://www.amazon.com/Chronos-GX-Touch-Chess-Clock/dp/B0015V3ZZ0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015V3ZZ0)

I am a concerned that the clock is a bit "scary-looking". It's also quite sturdy and made of metal (aluminum) so I guess (my Physics is a bit rusty) that it's like a Faraday cage with mostly empty space inside it (basically some tiny electronics, some wires and two AA batteries). As such, I am not sure how it shows / registers on the equipment they use and whether it might cause the operators to be concerned.

Is it safe to assume that I will be allowed to take it with me in the cabin as checked luggage?
Or should I perhaps take it with me to the airport already opened so they can inspect what's inside it? (there is a panel that you need to unscrew to change the batteries or see what's inside — so a screwdriver is required).

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't put it in checked-in bags?

Comment: @ReddHerring The reason is that it's brand new and expensive. Also, if a TSA agent wishes to examine the internals I want to be around and offer to unscrew the panel myself lest they damage it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the very same model of clock in scrabble tournaments. Our players fly all over the USA and the world with these clocks, mostly in hand luggage without any problems.

You should be fine.

Comment: This answer is why we are here. I will bounty this once the system lets me.

Comment: @chx What is the meaning of your comment?

Comment: This is an exemplary answer, one stemming from first hand experience which IMO is the goal of this site. It's also quite surprising how fast it came given the relative obscurity of the thing in question. And I will start a bounty on the question to award this answer accordingly but there is a period between a question is asked and a bounty can be started.